# Look-ahead on token stream?

Tags: programming

Is it possible to have a macro check, if it is followed by a given pattern of tokens and produce different expansions depending on it?

So far I have tried using code such as

```
\def\conditionalAction#1#2{
   \def\ca@tokens{{#1}{#2}}
   \def\ca@match{{\begin}{someenv}}
   \ifx\ca@tokens\ca@match                
     Matched.
   \else                                 
     Not matched.
   \fi
   #1#2%
}
```

but this has several severe limitations:

1. If used near the end of a file, it will result in a `File ended while 
   scanning use of \conditionalAction` error. This is important, when using 
   such a pattern to iterate over files.
2. It actually breaks, if either `#1` or `#2` is a token *group*. E.g. it will 
   transform `\begin{stuff}` into `\begin stuff`, which is wrong.

Workarounds are partly possible but impractical. E.g. it is possible to fix (1) by requiring, that each file ends with some end-marker, and (2) isn't relevant if the arguments compared against are discarded.

### Current usecase

While the question is more general for future reference, my current use-case is iterating over an input file, while discarding anything that is *not* inside a given environment. The idea is to provide a mechanism, that allows delaying the output of content to a later point (like the `apxproof` package, but without breaking synctex). Right now I am using a construct

```
\expandafter\SomeProcessFileMacro\@@input\InputFileNameAsMacro
```

where `\SomeProcessFileMacro` skips (using a pattern like `\conditionalAction` above) until it finds a sequence `\begin{apxenv}`, and is invoked again by `\end{apxenv}`. This mostly works and preserves synctex as intended, but I lack a mechanism for stopping at the end of the file.

The questions [SyncTeX with endnotes and apxproof packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432047/synctex-with-endnotes-and-apxproof-packages) and [Synctex: Variables for file name and line number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433002/synctex-variables-for-file-name-and-line-number) are related, but about other angles from which I tried to approach the problem.

Comment: There is the primitive `\futurelet` for a one-token lookahead and package `suffix`. But lookaheads with token lists in curly braces are cumbersome. Maybe, you can describe the problem for which you need the lookahead.

Comment: I added my current usecase. Since the patterns I am trying to check for are `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` neither `\futurelet` nor `\WithSuffix` are applicable.